# Undefined method "contain" for controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

It's definitely best to divide specs up so you have specs pertaining to each aspect of the MVC architecture, but I think there is a slight crossover with controller specs and view specs.

With view specs, you should only be concerned with the view, but with controller specs I still think it would be a good idea to test that the correct view is rendered, and maybe even test the content of the view, although more in-depth testing of the content should take place in the view spec.

Despite this clear article, https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views, describing how to do this, I just cannot integrate my view and controller specs.

*I keep getting the error undefined method 'contain'!*

Here's my spec_helper:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'


require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'ap'

def set(factory)
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(factory) 
end

def sign_up(first_name, last_name, profile_name, email, password)
    visit "/"
    click_link "Register"
    fill_in('First name', with: first_name)
    fill_in('Last name', with: last_name)            
    fill_in('Profile name', with: profile_name)
    fill_in('Email', with: email)
    fill_in('Password', with: password)
    fill_in('Password confirmation', with: password)
    click_button 'Sign up'
end

def sign_in(email, password)
    visit "/"
    click_link "Sign In"
    fill_in('Email', with: email)
    fill_in('Password', with: password)
    click_button 'Sign in'
end

def sign_out
    visit "/"
    click_link "Sign Out"
end



#Webrat.configure do |config|
#  config.mode = :rails
#end

#webrat

require 'capybara/poltergeist'
# Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist


Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium


Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)


RSpec.configure do |config|
  # true means 'yes, filter these specs'
  config.filter_run_excluding stress: true
 # config.current_driver = :webkit
#  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

#  config.include Capybara::DSL


  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation


  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

#  config.before(:suite) do
  #  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
 #   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
#    DatabaseCleaner.start
 # end

 # config.after(:each) do
 #   DatabaseCleaner.clean
 # end

  #config.after(:suite) do
#   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  #  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 # end


  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :feature

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true



  I18n.enforce_available_locales = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Here's my controller spec:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe UserFriendshipsController, type: :controller do
    render_views
    let (:user_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_1)} 

    before { 
        sign_in user_1
        get :index
    }   

    it "renders the :index view" do
        response.should render_template(:index)
    end

    it "view contains expected html" do
        # a sanity test more than anything
        response.should contain("Welcome to the home page")
    end
end
```

Upon running this spec I get this:

```
.F

Failures:

  1) UserFriendshipsController view contains expected html
     Failure/Error: response.should contain("Listing widgets")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `contain' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000008632268>
     # ./spec/controllers/user_friendships_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.1835 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

Why is this happening? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `include` instead of `contain`?

Comment: No, it's straight from the relish app website

Comment: Can you link that? I can't find such method there.

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Comment: Using `include` causes the expectation to hang until I kill it! Weird..

Comment: Ok, this is in 2.1 version and comes from Webrat, so if you really want to use it you should probably add `require 'webrat'` to config and add to config `config.include Webrat::Matchers` but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Right, I'm using the `match` keyword now. I think it was a very unclear article from Relish app, as like you say, `contain` is a method provided by webrat, not rspec. I add webrat to the Gemfile, the expectation passes. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [relish documentation for the current 2.14 version of Rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/controller-specs/render-views) you'll see that they're using `match` now instead:

```
expect(response.body).to match /Listing widgets/m
```

Using the `should` syntax, this should work:

```
response.body.should match(/Welcome to the home page/)
```

Comment: I know you shouldn't do this on this site, but thanks very much Dylan!

Comment: For anyone reading this in future - if they want to test not an exact match, but where a name is in the response, you can use this include matcher. e.g.: `expect(rendered).to include(@widgets.first.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Right, it was a very unclear article from Rspec that caused this error. It was using webrat in its example and didn't think to tell you. If anyone else gets here, you can add webrat to your gemfile to use the contain method:

*Gemfile*

```
group :test do
    gem 'webrat'
end
```

However, it makes a lot more sense to use rspec's native match method:

```
expect(response.body).to match /Listing widgets/m
```